# How to change the value of an xml node with jquery?

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax

This may be a simple question though can´t figure out how to do it.
I want to load and modify an xml file, then save the xml through php.

Here is the code:

```
 $.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "menu.xml",
  dataType: "xml",
  success: function(xml) {
   $(xml).find('menu_item').each(function(){
    //change the value of menu_item
    $(this).empty();
    $(this).text($("textarea").attr("value"));
    //send xml to php
    $.post('save_xml.php', $(xml), function(data){alert("Data Loaded: " + data);});
   }

  }
 });
```

Here is how save_xml.php looks like:

```
<?php

    $xml = $GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"];
    $file = fopen("file.xml","w");
    fwrite($file, $xml);
    fclose($file);
    echo "ok";

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

`$(this)` is each of the `menu_items` you iterate over with `.each()`

Your code becomes

```
$(xml).find('menu_item').each(function(){
   $(this).text("New Value");
});
```

Hope this helps

**EDIT**

To post this back to the server I would do this:

```
$.post('save_xml.php', { xml: $(xml)}, function(data){alert("Data Loaded: " + data);});
```

and then in the PHP file

```
<?php
  $xml = $_POST['xml'];
  $file = fopen("file.xml","w");
  fwrite($file, $xml);
  fclose($file);
  echo "ok";
?>
```

This code is untested, and there could be any number of reasons it doesn't work, write permissions on the files etc.

Comment: thanks, you were helpful! Now how do i send this xml to a php with jquery? i have a save_xml.php that writes the xml on the server.

Comment: @iulian Glad I could help. Please feel free to accept my answer. To pass the XML back to PHP you need `jQuery.post()` api.jquery.com/jQuery.post Where `data` is the XML you want to write.

Comment: I think so, for clarity, edit your question with the second part and I will modify my answer. That way you can insert your code clearly.

Comment: Thanks, I put the modifications. I hope that you can help me.

Comment: @iulian I have modified the data element that you were posting back to the php file

Comment: Does this solution actually work?  I'm doing something very similar but the new value I specify does not get preserved in the original XML object so the new value is not included in the POST.