# Not able to post xml data with jquery to server side(php)

Tags: php, jquery

what i am doing is:

1. reading a xml file with ajax get method
2. and then updating a particular node value of xml
3. after updating this xml response i am posting it to the server side (php) for writing that                xml file again

i am getting error in posting the updated xml response to server side
the error is: **NS_ERROR_XPC_BAD_CONVERT_JS: Could not convert JavaScript argument**

i found this accepted answer but this didn't work for me: [How to change the value of an xml node with jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4667067/how-to-change-the-value-of-an-xml-node-with-jquery)

here is my somecode:

```
$.ajax({
                url: "<?php echo $xmlFilePath;?>",
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "xml",
                success: function(xml){    

                    $(xml).find("Page[id='1']").each(function(){
                       $(this).find('ContentOne').text("New Value");
                    });

                 $.post('<?php echo base_url(); ?>contentadd', { xml: escape($(xml))}, function(data){alert("Data Loaded: " + data);});

                }
        });
```

any quick response will be helpfull

Comment: Which part of the error message `NS_ERROR_XPC_BAD_CONVERT_JS: Could not convert JavaScript argument` is hard for you to grasp?

Comment: @hakra actually i am sending xml response and it need to be escaped...i did that but still i didn't able to decode it in php script

Comment: You get an error message. So you do something *wrong*. You need to find out *what*. The error message helps you to locate the problem, but it looks like there is some missing part for you to just solve it. Can you explain which part you do not understand about the error? That part will help you to find the location where the error is created.

Comment: @hakra as i said that xml response was creating problem but by putting escape function it is loading now that error don't occur but ...the in php script i need to decode it and it's not doing that.....

Comment: You have not posted any PHP code here.

Comment: @hakra that is only a single line $xml = ($this->input->post('xml'));  i want to know how to decode that again ..which i have escaped xml content in jquery post method

Comment: @hakra can you tell me how to post the xml to sever side with jquery...after editing the xml node...or if u can share some link for me...i will be thankful to you

Comment: Did you try just `$.post('<?php echo base_url(); ?>contentadd', $(xml), function(data){alert("Data Loaded: " + data);});`?

Comment: `escape($(xml))` won't give you anything useful, btw.. (see the example: http://jsfiddle.net/naRqS/)

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6507293/convert-xml-to-string-with-jquery

Answer (score 0):

Instead of escape I would try to serialize xml with jQuery and unserialize it on server side...